# Adding file field dynamically in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working on an application where I have a form which has some form fields along with a file field. What I want is, to have a link or button "Attach another file" and it should append a new file field on click on that link. Something similar to gmail's file attachment functionality.

Any hint on how it can be implemented?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part, the HTML form or the Django form?

Comment: I am looking for a solution in django forms (i know some javascript is required along with django forms).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `formset` which, by definition, contains arbitrary number of forms. In your case, the form contains just a file field.

Documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

If you edit the number of forms on the page, via javascript, which you probably want to do, note that, you need to edit the [management form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform) values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually what I want is to put the link "Attach another" with the file field using django and put some javascript code to work with that link. I have to add the fields on the client side only, so frameset is not what I am looking for. I do not know how to put a link in django forms and associate a javascript with it.